# your branch is behind by 2 commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-commit

I have a branch of my master branch called 218.

I am the only one using this branch.

I commit my changes 3 weeks ago looking to do a pull request, but it was rejected as I needed to make changes.

Now I have made those changes and I wanted to commit the latest changes to my branch.

I tried to commit and it told me I needed to merge and pull. So I did, and it messed up all my files and got rid of my changes I made in the last 3 weeks.

I undid this by: `git reset --hard HEAD~1`

And now as it stands in my repo on my computer all the files are how they should be. But when I do git status, my changes dont show and it says:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/feature/218' by 2 commits, and can be fast forwarded. nothing to commit, working directory clean.
```

I want to make the branch what I have currently in my repo on my local computer as it stands and not pull anything down but overwrite everything with what I have locally.

How do I do this?

Comment: try `git reset --hard origin/feature/218` again.

Comment: I got this error because I had an uncommented local file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you are the only one working on the branch, you can overwrite the state of the remote branch by doing `git push --force`.

Though are you sure that you are the only one that is on the branch?  If you were the only one working on the branch, only your commits would have been on the remote and you would have had no need to do a `git pull`.

Doing `git push --force` with a shared branch will cause much more trouble for your team.  So make sure that you want to remove the 2 commits that are on the remote branch by doing the following:

```
git checkout origin/feature/218
git log -3
```

This will show that last three commits (the 2 you are behind and the last one you share) on the remote make sure that they are yours and that you want the last 2 to be overwritten.

Comment: git push --force won't cause any merging issues?

Comment: @Jesse I don't think there will be any issues with the pull request.  As per my answer, if the branch is shared there will be issues when other people try to push or pull updates.

Comment: how would you view which commits your branch is behind? is there a way to see commit hashes and messages of the commits you're behind by?

Comment: @AkinHwan that is in my answer, you can checkout the remote branch and do a `git log` to see the commits.  Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Answer (score 5):

```
git pull --rebase
```

I guess this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If your branch is behind by master then do:

```sh
git checkout master (you are switching your branch to master)
git pull 
git checkout yourBranch (switch back to your branch)
git merge master
```

After merging it, check if there is a conflict or not.
If there is NO CONFLICT then:

```
git push
```

If there is a conflict then fix your file(s), then:

```
git add yourFile(s)
git commit -m 'updating my branch'
git push
```

Comment: How do you verify there is no conflict after merging master?